# Procedimiento MySQL que utiliza valor en tabla como dato

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos MySQL, más específicamente utilizando PHPMyAdmin como interfaz. Por el momento tengo dos tablas: **price** y **info_airdrop**.
Lo que estoy intentando lograr es que diariamente se actualicen algunas columnas de mi tabla *info_airdrop* en función del último precio que tengo en la tabla *price*... Para hacer esto voy a utilizar procedimientos y eventos ya que quiero que la solución sea totalmente automática (esta parte la tengo ya resuelta).
Por el momento pude crear un procedimiento que actualiza mi tabla *info_airdrop* utilizando una variable de entrada que nombré **rps**:

```
  BEGIN 
        UPDATE info_airdrop set unlockedRPS = unlockedRPS +  diarioUSD / rps, 
               unlockedUSD = unlockedUSD + diarioUSD, 
               dias = dias + 1 
        WHERE unlockedUSD < totalUSD;
  END
```

Esto me funciona perfecto, pero me gustaría que esa variable de forma automática tome el valor del último posteo en mi tabla **price**, lo que me permitiria llamar a esta función todos los dias mediante un evento y ¡listo!.

La tabla price *tiene* los siguientes campos: ID (auto incrementable), price (con el precio), timestamp (con el timestamp del ultimo precio). La publicación de los registros en esta tabla lo realiza una script de forma automática cada 5 minutos, así que me parecía bueno aprovechar esta info.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si eso es un procedimiento, que te impide leer el ultimo valor de la tabla y guardarlo en una variable? o esa es tu pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

Pues seria hacer lo mismo pero con un trigger y lo solucionarías, esto hará que cada vez que cambie el valor de la tabla esta se actualice y incluso podrás hacer copias de lo que tenias antes

```
USE DB; 
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS prueba $$
CREATE TRIGGER prueba AFTER UPDATE ON tuTabla
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN 
        UPDATE info_airdrop set unlockedRPS = unlockedRPS +  diarioUSD / rps, 
               unlockedUSD = unlockedUSD + diarioUSD, 
               dias = dias + 1 
        WHERE unlockedUSD < totalUSD;
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

## Trigger o Disparadores.

Se trata de una rutina almacenada que se ejecuta de forma automática cuando se produce un evento

- INSERT, DELETE o UPDATE

Los Triggers se asocian a tablas (los procedimientos y funciones se asociaban a un BD).

## Las instrucciones asociadas a los disparadores son :

```
CREATE TRIGGER….
SHOW TRIGGER….
DROP TRIGGER… #Para modificar un Trigger que se borre y se reescribe
```

## ¿Cuando se dispara un trigger - Momento del disparo?

**BEFORE, AFTER (de la operación a realizar: INSERT, DELETE o UPDATE)
Esto nos da 6 posibilidades :** BEFORE INSERT, AFTER INSERT, BEFORE DELETE, AFTER DELETE, BEFORE UPDATE, AFTER UPDATE

## En una tabla no puede haber dos disparadores del mismo tipo (Ejemplo BEFORE DELETE)

**-FOR EACH ROW BEGIN….. END** Indica las instrucciones que hay que realizar con cada fila de datos

## Utilización de alias OLD y NEW

**Existen combinaciones que no tienen sentido :** INSERT con OLD y DELETE con NEW

## Programar Tarea para Ubuntu :

Abrimos el terminar.

Para crear la tabla para un trabajo, ejecutaremos el comando crontab con el argumento -e, que indica que queremos editar:

```
crontab -e
```

Para nuestro ejemplo de hoy, vamos a programar el apagado automático del ordenador, todos los días laborales a las 15:30 horas.

Como se trata de una tarea administrativa, deberemos utilizar el comando crontab con privilegios de root, por lo que escribiremos algo como esto:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Como cabe esperar, el sistema nos pide la contraseña de administración. La escribimos y pulsamos la tecla Intro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ocurre con otros comandos, crontab utiliza un editor de textos para que indiquemos nuestras preferencias, por lo que, la primera vez que lo ejecutamos, nos da a elegir entre los editores que haya instalados en estos momentos.

Las próximas veces entrará de forma automática en el editor que hayamos elegido.

Escribimos el número que representa a nuestro editor preferido y pulsamos la tecla Intro. En nuestro caso, mantenemos la opción predeterminada, que es el editor nano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de esto, en el área de trabajo del editor, aparece automáticamente el contenido del archivo que contendrá las tareas programadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En realidad, el contenido inicial del archivo no son más que líneas de comentario para instruirnos sobre el modo de programar tareas. Básicamente, la idea es que cada línea en el archivo de crontab tiene seis datos:

- **Minuto :** Un valor entero entre 0 y 59.
- **Hora :** Un valor entero entre 0 y 23.
- **Día del mes :** Un valor entero entre 1 y 31.
- **Mes del año :** Un valor entero entre 1 y 12.
- **Día de la semana :** Se puede expresar de dos formas:

  Como un valor entero entre 0 y 7, donde 0 ó 7 = domingo, 1 = lunes, 2 = martes, etc.

  Como un texto con los valores sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri y sat.
- Orden que será ejecutada por la Shell. crontab no analiza su contenido, sólo envía a la Shell cualquier cosa que haya después del día de la semana y hasta el final de la línea. Si aparece un carácter de porcentaje (%) será interpretado como el final de la línea por lo que, si necesitamos utilizar este carácter en la orden que le enviemos a la Shell, deberemos ponerle justo delante una barra invertida (%). Lo que haya antes del primer carácter de porcentaje es enviado a la Shell mientras que todo lo que haya después se envía a la entrada estándar.

Los primeros cinco datos pueden expresarse como valores individuales, como rangos de valores (expresados como dos valores separados por un guión), como una lista de valores individuales o rangos (separados por comas) o con un asterisco (*) que representa todos los valores posibles para ese dato.

También podemos indicar un valor de incremento usando el formato /número. Por ejemplo, si quiero que algo se ejecute entre las 5 y las 15 horas, pero sólo las horas impares, puedo escribir en la segunda columna algo como esto: 5-15/2

Como hemos dicho más arriba, para este artículo vamos a suponer que necesitamos programar el apagado automático del ordenador, todos los días laborales a las 15:30 horas. Para conseguirlo, nos desplazamos hasta la última línea del archivo y escribimos algo como esto:

```
30 15 * * 1-5 /sbin/poweroff
```

En este caso, he decidido utilizar el comando poweroff, pero podría haberme inclinado por halt o incluso por shutdown -r 0.

Aunque,si lo que necesitamos es reiniciar el equipo, debemos decantarnos por reboot.

Cuando terminemos de escribirla, salimos del editor pulsando las teclas ctrl + x y asegurándonos de guardar los cambios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llegados a este punto, es importante hacer dos observaciones:

1. La tarea programada se ejecutará con los privilegios de la cuenta en la que se ha creado. Si no hubiésemos utilizado el comando sudo, cuando llegara el momento de ejecutar la tarea, lo haría como si el usuario hubiese escrito la orden en ese preciso momento.
2. Si el ordenador está apagado cuando se cumple un plazo, la tarea no queda aplazada para cuando el equipo esté disponible. En otras palabras, la tarea correspondiente al plazo que se haya perdido no se recuperará.

Muchos comando que están pensados para usarlos con el servicio cron ofrecerán sus resultados generando sucesos con syslog. Puede resultar conveniente el uso de Logcheck para recibir periódicamente vía e-mail los sucesos que ocasionen estos comandos para tener la certeza de que se están ejecutando según lo planeado.

**URL :** http://somebooks.es/programar-una-tarea-repetitiva-desde-la-terminal-de-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

## Cómo programar tareas en Windows 10

Para configurar el programador de tareas, tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

- En el cuadro de búsqueda de Windows 10 escribe «programador de tareas» y haz clic para entrar.

  - Dentro del programador, verás un panel con las tareas que tienes programadas. Podrás empezar a crear tus tareas simplemente haciendo «crear tarea«.
  - En la pestaña de General, podrás indicar un nombre, descripción y ubicación, entre otros datos.
  - En la pestaña Desencadenar podrás elegir los días que quieres que se lance.
  - En Acción podrás elegir la ejecución de «algo». Aquí podrás decidir si quieres que se envíe un email (por ejemplo).
  - En Condiciones podrás añadir condiciones para la ejecución automática de la tarea.
  - Es ideal para programar a determinadas horas del día determinadas tareas/programas que quieres que se ejecuten.

Así de fácil es utilizar el programador de tareas en Windows 10. Simplemente, tendrás que crear tareas y guiarte por tu instinto, porque lo cierto es que es muy intuitivo y su funcionamiento se ha optimizado en esta última versión de Windows.

**URL :** https://www.profesionalreview.com/2017/02/18/programar-tareas-windows-10/

**URL :** https://www.adslzone.net/esenciales/windows-10/programar-tareas/

Comment: No entiendo para nada esta respuesta, y que tiene que ver con la pregunta... Que tiene que ver un trigger, con ejecutar algo todos los dias? no es lo mismo, y no tiene nada que ver...

Comment: ok.. pero mas alla que la pregunta tiene 2 meses (y 0 seguimiento) la pregunta dice: "Lo que estoy intentando lograr es que diariamente se actualicen algunas columnas de mi tabla info_airdrop en función del último precio que tengo en la tabla price..." o sea.. no quiere por cada cambio en la table.. quiere un evento programado diario.... Tu respuesta no tiene ningun error.. solo que me parece que no responde la pregunta en si...

Comment: si.. pero no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta... Nada de lo que pusiste esta mal, pero donde esta la respuesta a la pregunta, que es "Esto me funciona perfecto, pero me gustaría que esa variable de forma automática tome el valor del último posteo en mi tabla price, lo que me permitiria llamar a esta función todos los dias mediante un evento y ¡listo!.".. Todo eso, no esta respondido...